# Maven -DforkMode=never change user

Tags: java, maven

When I run project, it uses one user (for example *User1*) that set in my runner class, but if I want to debug, and set `-DforkMode=never` parameter, project runs with another user (for example *User 3*). Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Are you debugging Maven build with `mvnDebug` command or the tests running under maven-surefire-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-X` as a maven option and it should print out the java command it runs to perform the tests, this might shed some light on the issue. Could you please post your full command for running your tests i believe `-DforkMode=never` isnt a valid maven option past surefire `v2.14` but if you add the configuration like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more information see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html